# Is there a way to make caps lock behave like it does on other PCs?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Normally on a PC, if you have caps lock enabled, holding shift will result in lower case characters appearing.

```
Without Caps Lock

wITH cAPS lOCK
```

On OSX, this behavior doesn't occur - that is, holding shift while caps lock is engaged doesn't produce lower case. The behavior is specific to OSX, since it doesn't happen in a Boot Camp installed copy of Windows.

Is there a way to change this behavior to be more traditional?